OneSignal error: Landroid/app/Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks$-CC
I am using OneSignal version 5.1.10 on one of my Android applications but this error occurs.


FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.my.app, PID: 25840

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/app/Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks$-CC;

    at com.onesignal.core.internal.application.impl.ApplicationService.onActivityPostCreated(Unknown Source:0)

    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityPostCreated(Application.java:365)

    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityPostCreated(Activity.java:1360)

    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8081)

    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)

    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1330)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3636)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3820)

    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)

    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)

    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2218)

    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)

    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8005)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)

    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1039)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks$-CC

    ... 19 more

I tried upgrading the libraries but the error still occurs. I also tried using older versions but it's still the same.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
